# How to create a visual sitemap to Codeigniter Website

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

Please help me in creating a visual sitemap to codeigniter website, I am new to codeigniter the details are as follows.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this: http://enarion.net/tools/phpsitemapng/

Hope this helps!